# Using Selenium inside Flask App requires --no-sandbox when running in Docker

Tags: python, docker, google-chrome, security, selenium-webdriver

I have a Flask app that uses Selenium Chrome WebDriver to log in to a website and scrape some sensitive data off of it and securely store it in an encrypted file. Everything works perfectly locally. I am attempting to put this into a Docker container so it can be run easily on another machine. I am somewhat new to Docker and am running into problems. I can get it to finally work in Docker by adding the webdriver options --headless and --no-sandbox, but I have seen all the articles about how --no-sandbox is dangerous. However the single website that I am scraping from is trustworthy and I am not sure if --no-sandbox poses any threat unless the website you are accessing is potentially malicious. I do want to be very careful though because the data I am scraping is very sensitive. I have read and tried the answers in similar articles (i.e using the options 'remote-debugging-port=9222' or '--crash-dumps-dir=/tmp') but nothing works. **My questions are 1. How important is not using --no-sandbox for my use case (i.e. accessing one trusted website, but handling sensitive data), and 2. How can I get around it?!?!?**
My Dockerfile currently looks like this. I don't know what else to try at this point and any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
# Use the official Python image as the base image
FROM python:3.10.6
# Install necessary packages, including ChromeDriver
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    chromium \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get autoremove -y

# Set the PATH to include ChromeDriver location
ENV PATH="/usr/lib/chromium-browser:${PATH}"
RUN mkdir /app 
COPY . /app
COPY pyproject.toml /app 
WORKDIR /app
ENV PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${PWD} 
RUN pip3 install poetry
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install --no-dev
RUN pip3 install flask

# Expose the port the application runs on
EXPOSE 8000

# Define the command to run your application
CMD ["poetry", "run", "python", "run.py", "dashboard", "start", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

When running with the following options:

```
        options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run in headless mode
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Disable GPU for headless mode
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        options.add_argument('start-maximized')
        options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches',
                                        ['enable-automation'])
        options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
```

I get the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /root/.cache/selenium/chrome/linux64/117.0.5938.92/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

But when I add the --no-sandbox option, everything works correctly.

Comment: Hi there, can you make your question clear and clean~

Comment: Are you running the app as root? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71695438/why-do-i-need-no-sandbox-to-run-selenium-chromedriver-even-with-admin-privil

Comment: @MarekPuchalski I believe I am, but I couldn't get it to run as non-root in Docker

Comment: How about you try to do https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Docker_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-2-set-a-user. Just remember to chmod the whole directory with selenium resources.

Comment: @MarekPuchalski do you mean adding lines like              
COPY --chown=dylan . /app
RUN  chmod +x /app. This gives me the error virtualenv: error: argument dest: the destination . is not write-able at /home